# How to, using mongodb's aggregation or map/reduce, calculate fraction of users that have records every day, week and month

Tags: mongodb

Each MongoDB document looks like this (with properties that are irrelevant to this question being removed):

```
{
    "user_id" : 12345,
    "created" : ISODate("2013-06-17T20:10:10.741Z")
}
```

Trying to figure out how to, with aggregation queries or map/reduce, calculate fraction of users that have records every day, week and month.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can easily calculate the fractions in one go, but you can of course aggregate how many users there are in each of your bracket (day, week or month) although you'll have to run the aggregation three times.

First, for the day:

```
db.so.aggregate( [
    { $group: {
        _id: {
            y: { $year: '$created' }, 
            m: { $month: '$created' }, 
            d: { $dayOfMonth: '$created' }
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    } }
] );
```

Secondly for the month:

```
db.so.aggregate( [
    { $group: {
        _id: {
            y: { $year: '$created' }, 
            m: { $month: '$created' }, 
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    } }
] );
```

And lastly for the year:

```
db.so.aggregate( [
    { $group: {
        _id: { $year: '$created' }, 
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    } }
] );
```

Combine that with a distinct user count of the collection:

```
db.so.aggregate( [
    { $group: {
        _id: null,
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    } }
] );
```

You can then calculate the fractions as well.